# How do I make sure I copy objects and paste a duplicate of it in another artboard but keep the layer the same as the artboard before?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, artboard

I'm designing a website in Illustrator, and want to make multiple pages in one file using multiple artboards. So some elements need to be copied from page to page. I want to keep those elements in the same respective layer.

Comment: There is no direct connection between layers and artboards. They aren't associated with each other in any way.

Answer (score 3):

In the `Layer` panel open the panel options:
[image]
Check the option `Paste remembers layer`:
[image]

This also works across different Illustrator files.

Comment: You my friend, are epic.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please tick the "accepted answer" box and upvote. This is good for everyone, to know the problem has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

pasting an object will almost always paste to the layer that you have selected in the layers panel. so just double check what layer is selected when you're doing your copy/paste.